# Putting a submodule on the master branch if the checked out HEAD is the tip of master

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

Is it possible to checkout the master branch in each submodule if and only if the tip of master is the checked out commit?

It would be great if this could be in some hook so that I don't have to do it manually.

The reason I need this is that I can push the changed submodules content to origin and other remotes afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you can use `git-submodule foreach` to do stuff iteratively to each submodule. You could run your foreach, and do something like this to compare HEAD to master

```
$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) == $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master)
```

However, you may also be interested to know that you can tell submodules *not* to detach their HEADs when updating by defining the update property in `.gitmodules`. Find the submodule relevant submodule in `.gitmodules` and add an `update = rebase` or `update = merge` under it. This will mean when when you a submodule update, git will go into the submodule and instead of just checking out the commit directly (which detaches HEAD), it will perform either a pull or rebase.

Documentation is a bit shotty, but take a look at submodule.$name.update option, the --merge and --rebase update flags, and the --branch flag.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html

Comment: Ok, but this would checkout the latest version of the submodule even if the master repository was checked in with a previous version? I'm also not sure what happens if I want to switch branches for the submodule.

Comment: I tested it and if I go back to a previous version, the submodule is not restored to the previous state but remained in the "latest" state. I used the option update=rebase but I think it should not differ when using update=merge since my test history was linear. This is not acceptable.

Comment: The update=rebase options was just a suggestion as to how you might avoid the whole problem - but what your speicific problem/workflow is, is unclear. The direct answer to your question is to use the `git-submodule foreach` and compare the rev-parse output from HEAD and master